# Set position and dimentions of OXYPLOT C#

Tags: c#, plot, oxyplot

I am try to learn usage of oxyplot. When I show a plot on the form, the plot covers all the form area (shown below). I want to place it on spesific coordinates with dimentions.

How can I do that?

My code:

```
 private void Plot()
{

    PlotView pv = new PlotView();
    pv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(pv);

    LinearAxis XAxis = new LinearAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom };
    LinearAxis YAxis = new LinearAxis();
    PlotModel pm = new PlotModel();
    pm.Axes.Add(XAxis);
    pm.Axes.Add(YAxis);
    pm.Background = OxyColor.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
    pv.Model = pm;
    pv.Model.Series.Add(GetFunction());
}

private FunctionSeries GetFunction()
    {
        FunctionSeries fs = new FunctionSeries();
        for(int x=-10;x<=10;x++)
            for(int y=-10;y<10;y++)
            {
                DataPoint data = new DataPoint(x, y);
                fs.Points.Add(data);
            }
        return fs;
    }
```

The Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the PlotView on xaml, bind PlotView Model property to your PlotModel on code behind, and then, treat it as a normal Framework Element:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding pm}" Height="200" Width="200"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20"/>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any xaml file about my form. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry I thought that you were using WPF, but you are on windows forms. Maybe you can edit the same properties of the view on code behind, as you had been doing.

Comment: @ffttyy, In that case, just add 'pv' in the control-wrap instead of the main form.